# How to insert a set of object which Contains list of objects into Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to insert a set of object with Contain sub objects into Firebase, as shown in image. [Check this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfAn8.png).

Answer (score 0):

Well for firebase you have you create a DTO(data transfer object) to push it into the firebase, to push in the list of records for one node just create a list in that DTO which is being pushed in the fisebase i.e

```
    public class fruits{
         private long ser_fruit_id;
         // more properties
         private List<Items> listItems;// a list to push into firebase
         // getters and setters
    }
```

now ser_fruit_id will be pushed as node primary key which is in your image
under my data
0
1
2
3
4
// and so on

and listItems will be pushed as listItems in your image under mydata-> 0 -> listItems

another way is to directly push a list in the path

```
    mDatabase.child("0").setValue(listItems);
```

Or

```
    mDatabase.child("0").child("listItems").setValue(listItems);
```

I hope this clears all